# Primitive roots of odd primes

Tags: reference-request, elementary-number-theory

The following facts about primitive roots of an odd prime seem to be well known.  For example, they both appear as exercises in Burton's *Elementary Number Theory*.

> Let $p$ be an odd prime.  Then:
>   (1) Any primitive root of $p^2$ is a primitive root of $p^k$ for every positive integer $k$.
>   (2) Any odd primitive root of $p^k$ is a primitive root of $2p^k$.

I thought these facts might be from Gauss' *Disquisitiones Arithmeticae*, but I couldn't find them there.  Does anyone know the origin of these two facts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For what it's worth, Dickson, in his *History of the Theory of Numbers*, Chapter VII, page $186$, credits Jacobi (*Canon Arithmeticus*, $1839$) with the result that if $p$ is an odd prime, a primitive root of $p^2$ is a primitive root of $p^k$ for all $k> 2$.

Comment: Dickson says: *Jacobi proved that, if $n$ is an odd prime, any primitive root of $n^2$ is a primitive root of any higher power of $n$.* That gives us most of (1). I'm going to have to take a closer look at that chapter in Dickson to see if the rest is there. Thanks for this.

Comment: @Anononym: Yes, I only saw the prime power part in Dickson. The fact that it is also a primitive root of $p$ is barely worth noting, since it is clear that we can always go down.

Comment: Dear André: Your answer looks convincing to me. I think $(2)$ is an almost trivial consequence of $(1)$. +1!

Answer (score 0):

See [page 23](http://books.google.fr/books?id=hAFfb8BBC0IC&lpg=PP1&dq=intitle%3Aconcise%20inauthor%3Abaker&hl=fr&pg=PA23#v=onepage&q&f=false) and page 24 of Alan Baker's **A Concise Introduction to the Theory of Numbers**, or see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/91390/660).

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm not looking for a proof of those two facts about primitive roots.  I'm looking for their origin.  Specifically, I'd like to know who first proved these results.

Comment: Dear @Anononym: Sorry, I didn't read your question carefully enough. It's a good question: +1. I'll still leave my "answer" because, even if it doesn't *answer* the question, it adds a tiny bit to it (at least I hope so) by providing explicit references.